# Git Issue [Windows]: git push fatal error. GitBash and cmd not in Sync

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, bitbucket, railsinstaller

I'm new to git. I'm trying to push my new project up to my bitbucket repo but it doesn't seem to be working. I've added my ssh key correctly and run:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<username>/hello-app.git
```

*username has been replaced by my bitbucket username...*

This seems to have worked as when I run this again. It reads "fatal: remote origin already exists."

The console output from running the push is as follows:

```
C:\rails-dev\hello-app>git push -u origin --all
no such identity: /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repo exists on bitbucket and have had no problems running the local commands. Just the git push command. I've seen many questions on this site and tried solutions to no avail.

Currently my git is installed via the RailsInstaller. The commands above are run in a normal cmd prompt and not the GitBash shell.

edit: output of "git remote -v"

```
C:\rails-dev\hello-app>git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:c_parry/hello-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:c_parry/hello-app.git (push)
```

edit 2: output of running ssh -v -T git@bitbucket.org (in GitBash shell)

```
logged in as c_parry.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

output running same command in project directory.

```
C:\rails-dev\hello-app>ssh -v -T git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Christopher/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Christopher/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for     bitbucket.org
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Christopher/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa
no such identity: /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm thinking that my gitbash and my cmd are out of sync. But do now know what to check or change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Looking at the detailed logging in your updated question, there seems to be a discrepancy between the directory where it's successfully loading the ssh config file (/c/Users/Christopher/.ssh/) and the directory where it's looking for the keys (/c/Users/Christopher/ssh/).

It looks like your ssh config file is referring to the directory without a '.' at the start when it specifies the key.

(I've left the original answer below in case it's useful for someone else searching for similar error messages)

**Original Answer:**

The error message "no such identity: /c/Users/Christopher/ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory" is telling you that it's trying to use public-key authentication over ssh, and the identity file that it's looking for doesn't exist.

Basically you need to create an ssh identity and upload the public key to Bitbucket on the relevant settings page, then you should be good to go.

This page has a step-by-step tutorial: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

If you don't want to go through all of that, you can probably connect over https instead by specifying the relevant https URL in your "git remote add" line. The URL is probably something like: https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<username/>hello-app.git

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have already created an ssh identity and added the key to bitbucket. I log on correctly via ssh when I run the command 'ssh -v -T git@bitbucket.org'. However, when I am trying to run this outside of the GitBash via cmd in the local directory of my project I get an error. Updated answer with both outputs.

Comment: Looking at the detailed logging in your updated question, there seems to be a discrepancy between the directory where it's successfully loading the ssh config file (/c/Users/Christopher/.ssh/) and the directory where it's looking for the keys (/c/Users/Christopher/ssh/). I suspect that your ssh config file is referring to the directory without a '.' at the start when it specifies the key.

Comment: update the answer and I will accept it. The .ssh was the issue in the config file. Just need fresh eyes sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

To push data into bitbucket repository you need to have user account in bitbucket also the write permission for repository. Please verify.

Comment: I've got a bitbucket account and write permission.

Comment: regarding error  "fatal: remote origin already exists" : Adding remote is one time process so you should not run it again.